# Replacing text on a Squarespace button

Tags: css, squarespace

I'm trying to modify the automatically inserted text on a button you get to click on to access an event page.
I've been able to add the text I want to display ('Je participe') but not to hide the text that's automatically inserted ('Voir l'événement').

Here's the page link: maisonmariet.fr/evenements

And here's my code:

```
.eventlist-button.sqs-editable-button:before {
   display: none !important;
}
.eventlist-button.sqs-editable-button:after {
   content: 'Je participe →'!important;
}
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `content: ''` for `::before`

```
.eventlist-button.sqs-editable-button::before {
   content: '' !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing.

Comment: You can remove these classes and add this to your js file. document.getElementsByClassName('eventlist-button')[0].innerText = 'Je participe →';